# How to find element in JavaScript for selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium

How do I find element for the above code? I need to find find the element and click link "create user". I m using Webdriver and the page is built on JavaScript. I cannot locate Xpath and the only thing i can view is the class

```
<a class="toolbarButton"> create user </a>
```

Comment: which selenium driver you are using ?

Comment: WebDriver.....
     
i tried it using by.classname it says no elements were found. Do i need to use javascriptexecutor class?

Answer (score 0):

For webdriver, you can use:

```
findElement(By.className('toolbarButton'));
```

You can also find by name, tag, id, etc... More info [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html)

Comment: How do I find element for the above code? I need to find find the element and click link "create user". I m using Webdriver and the page is built on JavaScript. I cannot locate Xpath and the only thing i can view is the class

    <a class="toolbarButton"> create user </a>

Comment: The line of code I posted is how you would find the element in your question. You can then add `.click()` to click on it. Have you read the link I included, or done any tutorials? If not, you should.

Comment: i tried it using by.classname it says no elements were found. Do i need to use javascriptexecutor class?